# Oracle APEX REST API Nested JSON output

Tags: arrays, json, rest, oracle-apex-22

I wrote the below code which is not showing my desired output. I want to show the output exactly the same as I have in the screenshot. I have created the REST API in Oracle APEX version 22.2 and the database version is 19c.

```sql
SELECT 'application/json' as content_type, JSON_OBJECT (
    KEY 'departments' VALUE (
        SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
            JSON_OBJECT (
                KEY 'department_name' VALUE d.DEPARTMENT_NAME,
                KEY 'department_no' VALUE d.DEPARTMENT_ID,
                KEY 'employees' VALUE (
                    SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG (
                        JSON_OBJECT (
                            KEY 'employee_number' VALUE e.EMPLOYEE_ID,
                            KEY 'employee_name' VALUE e.FIRST_NAME))
                    FROM   OEHR_EMPLOYEES e
                    WHERE  e.DEPARTMENT_ID = d.DEPARTMENT_ID)))
        FROM   OEHR_DEPARTMENTS d
        where d.DEPARTMENT_ID in (10,20,30)))
AS departments
FROM dual
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add what you are getting? I tried your query, it gives me exactly the same structure ```{"departments":[{"department_name":"ACCOUNTING","department_no":10,"employees":[{"employee_number":7839,"employee_name":"KING"}...```

Do you mean the formatting/spacing?

Comment: @NormanAberin i am getting below output when add same query in  GET API in oracle apex
"depts": "{\"dept\":{\"deptno\":\"Admi\",\"deptno\":10,\"emp\":[{\"empno\":200,\"empname\":\"Jennifer\"}]}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember this, I mainly use this for when I forget https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2017/09/ords-returning-raw-json/. Here you will need to prefix your column with `{}`. In your query, you just need to change the column name from:

- `departments` to `"{}departments"`

Comment: Thank you @NormanAberin It's working fine